# Microsoft graph one drive id based webUrl

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft graph provides two properties for displaying item in browser: webUrl and webDavUrl. webUrl is sometimes id based and sometimes path based. From what I read in another stackoverflow question webDavUrl is always path based. Is there some way to always construct an id based url rather than a path based one? The problem with path based is that when some folder name changes then that affects the url of all the files and folders from that folder down.

LT

Answer (score 1):

These are managed/generated by SharePoint, not Microsoft Graph. Instead of storing the `webDavUrl` or `webUrl` values directly, you should consider storing the `id` for the `DriveItem` and querying for the correct URL at runtime. Unlike the path, the `id` won't change if the file is moved within a `drive` (assuming the move was done by deleting and re-uploading the file).

Comment: Thanks Marc. Yes, that's what we went to since we were hoping but we weren't expecting that there was any predicable id based view url.